# Convert fabric freedrawing path to openlayers freedrawing geojson

Tags: fabricjs, openlayers, geojson

Is there a way to convert a path from fabricjs freedrawing to openlayers freedrawing in geojson, so i can reuse my previously drawn fabric paths on openlayer?

Thank you.

Comment: If you can save your path as SVG, you can then transform SVG to GeoJSON (by [svg2geojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg2geojson), for example).

Comment: Thanks [unibasil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1572775/unibasil). I'll give it a try.